# nmcli dev connect?

Tags: nmcli

nmcli has an option to disconnect a device ( `nmcli dev disconnect iface mydevice`) but it doesn't have a `connect` command. How can I connect a device which was disconnected? My device is not a wifi.

nmcli device { COMMAND | help }

COMMAND := { status | list | disconnect | wifi }

Answer (score 0):

`nmcli` connects "connections", not "devices". So, read `man nmcli` and use something like:

```
nmcli con up id Nick iface wlan0
```

Comment: Ok but I've disconnected the device using `nmcli dev disconnect iface` and now I'm wondering how to connect it back. As the device is "disconnected"  I can't bring up the connection with nmcli conn up/

Comment: If you read the man page, they have examples at the end.  One of them is  `nmcli -p con up id "My wired connection" iface eth0`. Replace "My wired connection" with your network's id and `eth0` with your interface name.  You don't really need `-p ` flag, but you could use that to see progress.